# Can we use the UINavigationController animation on UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using `UITabBarController` so that it can be displayed on all views once declared in `delegate`, but my requirement is that when any tab bar button clicked it should work like a button works on `pushViewController`:. Is it possible, can anyone guide here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- you can just create a `UINavigationController` with toolbar hidden.
- Then create a root view controller which has `toolbar or custom view` on bottom and add buttons on it.
- Add targets to that buttons to `push view controllers` which you want.

Comment: There's nothing to stop you from starting with a UINavigationController and then the RVC being a UITabBarController also.

Comment: I am already having a custom view as bottom bar, but the problem is that how can i show it on all views, that's why i moved to tab bar.

Comment: I thought you don't want that. So you have created a controller which has bottom bar. Now for every controller you want to use, just subclass from that controller. Then you have bottom bar in all of your controllers. Another way is to add that custom view to the view of navigation controller. Then you have always that custom view while you are in stack of navigationcontroller. Respectively you need to resize the view of your view controllers.

Comment: How can you do the push view controller in delegate? Its not allowed there.

Comment: [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES] I advise you to read guide here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH2-SW1

Comment: Thank you, but please tell me, is pushViewController works in delegate class.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a typical behavior, however you can try as follows:

Declare a delegate (UITabBarDelegate) for your UITabBar, and implement the method `-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item` to get notified of the user selecting tabs. In this method you will push a new view controller in the navigation controller's stack (or pop one that is not desired).

Depending on your needs, you may also need to manually set the currently selected tab bar item. To do so you can manipulate the tab bar's `@property(nonatomic) NSUInteger selectedIndex`. Be aware that changing this property will trigger another call to `tabBar:didSelectItem:` which may or may not be wanted.